# Django - Site.objects.get_current().domain returns example.com

Tags: python, django

I currently have a Django app running on Amazon EC2. I have this code inside my Django app which basically has this code

```
 if not 'request' in self.context:
        #In case we dont have a context
        current_site = Site.objects.get_current().domain
        ret['employer_image'] = current_site + ret['employer_image']
```

now `Site.objects.get_current().domain` is returning `example.com` any suggestions on why its  returning example.com ? I can always hard code the url but I wanted to know why this was failing ?

Comment: Probably because you have configured the [django sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/sites/#module-django.contrib.sites). If you want to get the current host, I think you should use [request.get_host()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host) instead.

Comment: Came here with the same — despite adding correct domain in Sites admin and setting `SITE_ID` in settings was getting `example.com`. (On Heroku) purging repo cache and redeploying magically fixed the problem

Answer (score -1):

django.contrib.sites registers a post_migrate signal handler which creates a default site named example.com with the domain example.com.

This site will also be created after Django creates the test database.

To set the correct name and domain for your project, you can use a data migration.

This comes from the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/sites/